# Android Take Screen Shoot from Background by Service

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, screenshot

I want to take screen shoot in android.
So when i use code like this

View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

its only giving my app screen shoot .

But i want to screen shoot hole android device.whatever user open application.

Suppose my service is ready to start take screen shoot every 10 sec. Now when user open contact no. or other application my application continuously taking screen shoots of a every application which are on Screen.

Thanks in advance.
And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you cannot implement that kind of spyware in non rooted devices

Comment: Fortunately, this is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. The exceptions are rooted devices and Android 5.0+, which has some abilities to do screenshots and screencasts, but the user is involved (you have to display a system-supplied activity, for the user to agree to the recording)